# Shortening the search process of binary value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out if there is a faster way to find matching numbers for this condition inside the loop:

```
        List<int> l = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        {
            l.Add(i);
        }

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> k = GetPermutationsWithRept(l, 4).ToArray();

        foreach (IEnumerable<int> item in k)
        {
            int[] comb = item.ToArray();
            if (((comb[0] & 3) << 6 & 192 | (comb[1] & 3) << 4 & 48 | comb[2] & 12 & 12 | (comb[3] & 24) >> 3 & 3) == 178)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(comb[0].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(comb[1].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(comb[2].ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(comb[3].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I assume that the optimizer takes care of `comb[2] & 12 & 12`. In `(comb[3] & 24) >> 3 & 3` the `& 3` is redundant.

Comment: Maybe some context would help? What is this combination for?

Comment: The best optimization I imagine would be to forgo the `item.ToArray()` call.  I suspect that is orders of magnitude more time consuming than some bit-wise operators.  Although this is probably premature optimization too, does it need to be any faster?  Good blog article related to your problem: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: The general form seems to be: mask off a pair of adjacent bits, shift them, mask them again for good measure, then combine the intermediate results. Seems that the redundant masking could be removed with no harm.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did remove redundant mask, but it's fractions faster. It does take a quite a bit of time to find the right combination.

Comment: I think the answer to this will depend on things like - know many items do you get in the `k` array on average? Are you sure it is not the call to `GetPermitationsWithRept()` that is taking most of the time?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up re-writing the piece of code in C++ and it completes in just 20 seconds. Something that has been going on for about 12 hours on c# side. I'm really amazed how quickly it got done in C++.